# How to sort array elements, so that the length of maximum chain of same elements is shortest (eg:AAAABC to ABACAA)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

For example, I want to decrease the length of maximum length of chain of same elements until the length of chain is min,eg:

```
["A","A","B","B","A"] to ["A","B","A","B","A"] (max chain from 2:AA,BB to 1:A,B)
["A","A","A","B","B","C"] to ["A","B","A","B","A","C"] (max chain from 3:AAA to 1:A,B,C)
["A","A","A","A","B","C"] to ["A","A","B","A","C","A"] (max chain from 4:A to 2:A, not ["A","A","B","A","A","C"] because if max length of chains are the same, select one that contains less number of max length of chains)
["A","A","A","A","B","B"] to ["A","B","A","A","B","A"] (also not ["A","A","B","A","A","B"] because it has 2 AA instead of 1)
```

How to write that functions to sort it? I tried:

```js
const magicSort=function(arr){
  const countMap={};
  for(const e of arr){
    countMap[e]==null?countMap[e]=1:countMap[e]++;
  }
  const positionArr=[];
  for(const key of Object.keys(countMap)){
    for(let i=0;i<countMap[key];i++){
      positionArr.push({"key":key,"value":i/countMap[key]});
    }
  }
  positionArr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.value-b.value;
  });
  for(let i=0;i<positionArr.length;i++){
    positionArr[i]=positionArr[i].key;
  }
  document.write(JSON.stringify(positionArr));
  document.write("<br/>");
}
magicSort(["A","A","B","B","A"]);
magicSort(["A","A","B","B","C"]);
magicSort(["A","A","A","A","B","C"]);
```

which calculates the position when each element is evenly distributed in the original length of array, and then sort that evenly distributed position, but the output of `["A","A","A","A","B","C"]` is `["A","B","C","A","A","A"]` instead of `["A","A","B","A","C","A"]`.

Order of other elements doesn't need to maintain here, and the shortest chain rule should apply to "A" and "B" (all other elements) instead of only "C", other examples:

```
AABBBCCCCCCCC to CBCBCACACCBCC (two 2C chains)
AABBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCC to CCCBCCBCCACCACCBCCC (two 3C chains)
AAABBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC to CCACCACCACCBCCCBCCCBCCCBCCCBCCCBCCC (six 3C chains)
```

Comment: Do you need to keep a certain order with the elements or with same elements ? Like `A,B,C` is the same result for you as `B,C,A` respectively `A0,B,A1` is the same as `A1,B,A0` .

Answer (score 4):

Take your `countMap` entries so that you have each character and its frequency - with that, you can iterate over the entries, alternating between the two largest ones that are left, until it's fully exhausted. (For example, given 10 Xs, 10 Ys, and 1 Z, you'd leave the Z until close to the end by recognizing that the Xs and Ys remain as the two highest counts until they get down to 1 left)

```js
const magicSort = (arr) => {
  const countMap = {};
  for (const e of arr){
    countMap[e] = (countMap[e] || 0) + 1;
  }
  const entries = Object.entries(countMap);
  const sorted = [];
  let last;
  while (entries.length) {
    const entry = entries.reduce((a, b) => {
      // Return new value if current value is a dupe
      if (a[0] === last) return b;
      // Return current value if new value is a dupe
      if (b[0] === last) return a;
      // Return entry with highest count
      return b[1] > a[1] ? b : a;
    });
    last = entry[0];
    sorted.push(last);
    entry[1]--;
    if (!entry[1]) {
      entries.splice(entries.indexOf(entry), 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(sorted);
};
magicSort(["A","A","B","B","A"]);
magicSort(["A","A","B","B","C"]);
magicSort(["A","A","A","A","B","C"]);
magicSort(["A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"]);
```

Comment: That's a nice solution! Could you explain a bit how the `reduce` method is doing the job for this behind the sences?  Thanks.

Comment: `.reduce` lets you compare each array element against itself and keep the most suitable one as the accumulator (the first argument to the callback - here, named `a`). If `a[0] === last`, then the character is the same one just inserted, so it should be avoided if possible. Otherwise, `a[1] > b[1] ? a : b` will select the entry remaining in the array with the highest count left.

Comment: Wow, that a very short way for doint that, awesome... Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, a brief explanation:

1. Divide the array into groups of letters
2. Sort groups by length in nested arrays
3. Get the first elements of the first two nested arrays
4. Create rest of groups
5. Create a pair for the result
6. Repeat 2-5 if groups are containing more than one nested array

```js
const magicSort = (arr) => {
  const result = [];
  let groups = Object.values(arr.reduce((r, e) => ({ ...r, [e]: [...(r[e] ?? []), e] }), {}));
  
  while (groups.length > 1) {
    const sorted = groups.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
    const [[first, ...firstRest], [second, ...secondRest], ...groupsRest] = sorted;
    groups = [firstRest, secondRest, ...groupsRest].filter(group => group.length);
    result.push(first, second);
  };
  
  result.push(...groups.flat());
  return result;
}

console.log(...magicSort(["A","B","C"]));
console.log(...magicSort(["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"]));
console.log(...magicSort(["A","A","B","B","C"]));
console.log(...magicSort(["A","A","A","A","B","C"]));
console.log(...magicSort(["A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```